# Android webview loaddata giving NullPointerException

Tags: android, html, webview, nullpointerexception, loaddata

I have used a webview named `Testview` to load html data in the webview. for that I am using the following code.

`Testview.loadData("<html><body>helloindia</body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8");`

I have given `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in the manifest. But this above loine of code is generating `NullPointerException`. Can anyone point out the problem in my code?

Comment: can you pls add whole code snippet?

Comment: Are you sure that Testview is initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @m0s pointed in comment: make sure Textview [is initialized](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#WebView%28android.content.Context%29):

```
textview = new WebView(this);  // used inside an Activity
```

Also, it is a Java custom to write class names with first letter capitalized (WebView) and instances with first letter in lower-case (textview), so that they are easily distinguished.

**Update:**

If this line returns null:

```
Textview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.testview)
```

then you most probably forgot to call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

in your `activity.onCreate()` method. The javadoc of findViewById(int) says:

```
Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML THAT WAS 
PROCESSED in onCreate(Bundle).
```

That's what `setContentView()` does (processes the layout XML):

```
Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated,
adding all top-level views to the activity.
```

Comment: Textview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.testview);

Comment: Actually I have the change the view in a view.OnClickListener and set a new xml for the new view which contains the WebView.
setContentView(R.layout.weblayout);
testview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.testview);
the problem is solved when I removed the 'this' before findViewById. But this line of code run properly in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) of Activity. Can you tell me the reason behind it?

Comment: `this` inside the `view.OnClickListener()` refers to the anonymous class, not to the enclosing view class.